# Laravel 5.2 - set Primary key to email instead of 'id'

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {<br>
            $table->primary('email');<br>
            $table->string('name');<br>
            $table->string('image_url');<br>
            $table->string('signin_with');<br>
        });
```

Above is my Database Schema.

Here is my Users **model**.

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'users';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'email';

    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'name' ,'image_url', 'signin_with'
    ];
}
```

Now my question is I want to make 'email' attribute as primary key in users table. but i get an error of

> QueryException SQLState[42S01].

How can i solve ?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You probably don' want to set email as `primary key`. Most likely you wish to set it as `unique` and add `index` to it, since primary key is used for increment purposes also.

Comment: I could be wrong, but SQLState[42S01] suggests to me that the table already exists. Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: i don't want email id to be null as i can assign it to `unique` then it will be only one entry of email in that table but it can also be null that thing i don't want to . and i need that email id in other table as `foreign key` and `composite key` . 

The error is 

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary key is used for linking to other tables and string comparison is slower than int comparison.

If you store users information in multiple tables, the foreign keys to the users table will be the e-mail address.

That means that you store the e-mail address multiple times.
So, instead of using email as primary key use an auto-incremented primary key.

Comment: yes.. i store email in table because email id will be in use in other table and based on our requirements email id should be primary key. so how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In your User Schema:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('email')->unique();
```

In the model of something that needs a User

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

You'll have a foreign key on an indexed field. No need to have the primary key on this field for the Users table.

Based on https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#creating-indexes