# Set email as a primary key in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-8

I want to create an email as a primary key instead of id in laravel migration, I've tried.

```php
public function up()
{
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->primary('email');
  });
}
```

and I've got an error like below:

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:
> column "email" of relation "users" does not exist (SQL: alter table
> "users" add primary key ("email"))

Comment: Email is not used as a primary key normally. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526617/laravel-5-2-set-primary-key-to-email-instead-of-id

Answer (score 2):

Email is not used as primary key normally and it's a bad habbit to do so. if you still want to do it you can do it something like this:

```
{
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('email')->primary();
  });
 }
```

Please note it's NOT Recommended!

Answer (score 0):

Using Email as a primary key is not recommended and considerd a bad practice. However, if you want to do it you can do the following migration:

```
{
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('email')->primary();
  });
 }
```

However, if you need the email to be unique for each user and also the id to be primary key which is a better practice, you can do the folloiwng:

```
{
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->string('email')->unique();
  });
 }
```